# How to initiate the collaboration 'talk'?

Tags: collaboration

Following my question **How to effectively e-mail a professor I met briefly about collaborative work?** [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108710/how-to-effectively-e-mail-a-professor-i-met-briefly-about-collaborative-work), I managed to convince the professor for collaboration. Now he has linked me to his post-docs and a Ph.D. student (his emphasis was more on the Ph.D. student).

He told me to contact them and see how we can collaborate. (actually he sent an email keeping all of us in CC, i.e. me and his post-docs and PhD student).

Now I have an idea that I should read a couple of student's paper and then proceed in the direction. But what would the veterans in the academia suggest should be my approach so as not to miss this opportunity?

PS. Not sure the second tag is correct or not!

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? As I remember the original question, you had a project and just wanted to use their testbed. But now it sounds like you're trying to joint this group.

Comment: Yes, I want to use their test-bed. I don't want to join their group AS OF NOW. First I just want to use their test-bed. The thing is using their test-bed, I need to inline my research with the research group as we are working in the same thing, but using two different technology. (wifi vs cellular)

IMPLICITLY, I aim to impress the professor and research group to join them (but as of now this is not my aim).